# Can't assign a QString as a value for a LineEdit in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oop, user-interface

I am working on a simple calculator app in Qt. I want to display an error message when the user tries to divide by zero. I have tried the code below but the output just stays as 0.

```
            if(dblDisplayVal == 0.0){
            QString error = "Can't divide by zero!";

            ui->display->insert(error);
        }
        else{
            result = calcVal / dblDisplayVal;
            divTrigger = false;

        }
```

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: insert got two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [setText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) function instead of `insert`.

**this is an example:**

```
QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);
ui->gridLayout->addWidget(lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1);

QString  error = "Can't divide by zero!";

lineEdit->setText("Can't divide by zero!");
```

**and it is the output:**

[image]